# Can there only be 1 constructor per class or multiple?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am a bit confused with it comes to constructors in javascript. I am under the impression that constructors are used to create new objects with template data that you fill in later during the instantiation process. However, I am told that you can only have ***ONE*** constructor per class.

In my code below, I use multiple methods in my Actor object to create stats for my player characters in a 1vs1 game I am building. From a glance to me, it looks like I am using 3 constructors for my actor object. However, they say you can only have 1 constructor. So now I am a bit confused.

Did I really create 3 constructors here or did I just create 3 functions that are not constructors? I really am not understanding the difference between them. Can someone help clarify a few things for me.

1. Am I using a constructor in my Actor Object?
2. Am I using 3 constructors in my Actor Object if yes.
3. If no, should I be using a constructor or is what I have here just fine?

Thanks for reading and the help.

```
let Actor = {
    primaryStats: function (level, hp, balance, exp){
        this.level   = level;
        this.hp      = hp;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.exp     = exp;
    },
    primaryStatsBase: function (levelbase, hpbase, balancebase, expbase){
        this.levelbase   = levelbase;
        this.hpbase      = hpbase;
        this.balancebase = balancebase;
        this.expbase     = expbase;
    },
    primaryStatsCap: function(levelcap, hpcap, balancecap, expcap){
        this.levelcap   = levelcap;
        this.hpcap      = hpcap;
        this.balancecap = balancecap;
        this.expcap     = expcap;
    },
};

let New = Object.create;

let player = New(Actor);

let dwarf   = New(player);
let human   = New(player);
let elf     = New(player);

human.primaryStats(1, 9000, 100, 1);
human.primaryStatsCap(1, 9000, 100, 1);
human.primaryStatsBase(1, 9000, 100, 1);
```

Comment: "*However, I am told that you can only have ONE constructor per class.*" yes. "*From a glance to me, it looks like I am using 3 constructors for my actor object*" which is not *a class. Also, you've created essentially three factory methods. They are "constructor functions", however, *a lot of* regular functions can also be called that. Because they can be called with `new` and produce a somewhat meaningful result in that case. Which is most of the requirement for a "constructor function".

Comment: _"Did I really create 3 constructors here or did I just create 3 functions that are not constructors?"_ You created 3 functions that are not constructors. Read [MDN: constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor). You don't have any constructor in your code. The question _"If no, should I be using a constructor or is what I have here just fine?"_ is asking for opinions and explicitly off-topic.